# Using selected_related() in nested serializers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've been using `select_related()` to speed up a large DRF call with great success, but I've hit a wall.

My main serializer references two other serializers, and one of those references yet another serializer. I'm unsure as how to implement prefetching in the second level serializer.

serializer.py

```py
class DocumentsThinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Documents
        fields = ('confirmed', )


class PersonThinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    documents = DocumentsThinSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('name', 'age', 'gender')


class EventThinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    day = DayThinSerializer()
    person = PersonThinSerializer()

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        return queryset.select_related('day', 'person')

    class Meta:
        model = Event
```

views.py

```py
class EventList(generics.ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventThinSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.get_serializer_class().setup_eager_loading(queryset)
```

As you can see, I'm using the static method `setup_eager_loading()` to get things going, but I can't find a queryset hook for my `PersonThinSerializer()` to get the speedup when accessing the `DocumentsThinSerializer()` in the same way.

Comment: Care to show the models for Event, Person and Document so we can see the relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Documents` has a foreign key to `Person`, you should be able to add `"person__documents"` to your `queryset.select_related` in `EventThinSerializer.setup_eager_loading`:

```
class EventThinSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    day = DayThinSerializer()
    person = PersonThinSerializer()

    @staticmethod
    def setup_eager_loading(queryset):
        return queryset.select_related('day', 'person', 'person__documents')
```